# Transitioning from SVN to Git (git-svn, multiple branches in workspace and no dependency management)!

Tags: java, git, svn

We are currently trying to pilot the transition from Git to SVN to increase production and collaboration within our team.

However we are facing some issues with trasitioning and finding counterparts which currently work for us. I've been reading up on Git and can't seem to find a **specific** answer.

Here are some issues:

1. Our project is composed of several subprojects each built as a project of its own. How do we manage these subprojects with Git? One of the main issues I've encountered is when switching branches, I have to  individually switch branches among

   I've read about Subproject support as mentioned in https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SubprojectSupport, but I've also read that this isn't supported by git-svn.
2. We have multiple SVN branches currently, each representing a release. Most of us have all relevant branches (usually 2-3) checked out in our workspace. Switching branches might be okay if it's fast, but another problem is the configuration of our build paths & etc (considering we don't have any dependency management system in place at our level of development and all are done manually). Is there a way to go around this in Git, either by allowing multiple branches active in a workspace, or through rapid switching?

I'm not sure if there will be any specific correct answer, but pointing me to relevant resources will be helpful as well. Thank you.

Comment: You write "from Git to SVN", but your text seems to imply you currently use SVN and want to go to Git. Which is it?

Comment: I clarified the title. Seems there was a mix-up. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather broad (or possibly contains multiple questions), but I'll try a general answer:

> Our project is composed of several subprojects each built as a project
>   of its own. How do we manage these subprojects with Git?

Usually you would put these into one Git repo, each in its subdirectory. You can use multiple repositories, but that only makes sense if the projects are versioned, branched and released independently. Branches are always per repository in Git (unlike in SVN, where you branch a single directory), so the rule of thumb is: What is branched together shares on repo, what is branched separately gets its own repo.

> We have multiple SVN branches currently, each representing a release.
>   Most of us have all relevant branches (usually 2-3) checked out in our
>   workspace. Switching branches might be okay if it's fast, but another
>   problem is the configuration of our build paths & etc (considering we
>   don't have any dependency management system in place at our level of
>   development and all are done manually). Is there a way to go around
>   this in Git, either by allowing multiple branches active in a
>   workspace, or through rapid switching?

You cannot have multiple branches checked out in one working directory (how would that even work?). You can make multiple clones (each with its own working directory), then check out different branches. However, I'm not sure that is the best solution for you.

Switching branches in git is very fast - essentially just the time for the filesystem I/O required to change the files that need changing.

About the build paths: If you switch branches in git, the paths do not change, because the switch happens inside the working directory.

A final note: It looks like you should really look into some kind of dependency management and artifact management. Doing all this with source code only is rather error-prone and difficult.

Comment: With regards to switching branches, my concern was that since we have multiple (currently 7-8) subprojects as dependencies each released and maintained on its own (and all in active development), that would require switching branches on each one to a compatible branch. Currently, with SVN, we have the option to checkout all needed branches of all projects into a single workspace so there really won't be any "switching" necessary-- all branches are already accessible from then on.

Comment: @Chad: Yes, as I said, you should really look into dependency/artifact management. In the meantime, if the projects are released independently, you can (and should) put each into its own git repo. Then you can put the checked-out copies side-by-side as you need them. Or perform some magic with filesystem/symbolic links...

Comment: So there would be no workaround to switching the branches of all projects together? For example our main project requires version 1.1 of A, 1.5 of B, 4.2 of C and etc. Is there a way for me to switch all these projects at the same time?

Comment: @Chad: Oh my, just how do you even keep track of what versions you need? Anyway, no, there's no mechanism in git for this. You could whip up a script to do the switching for you though (git is easy to script, since it works on the command line). You could even check this in with each version or the main project, so you check out the main project, run the checkout script, and you're good to go.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into git "submodules" and "subtrees". They address a similar problem.